# Looking to Maximize CPU Utilization with a python benchmarking program using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking, concurrent.futures, stress-testing

I have been working on developing a synthetic benchmarking program in python in order to stress-test the CPU in various systems for a class project. I have based my approach on Mersenne primality tests (inspired by prime95). The program is intended to test the Mersenne primality of numbers over a working set, defined by the user. I have so far implemented this in python, however once implementing the concurrent.futures module in order to run the task in parallel to maximize CPU utilization, I hit a snag. When testing my program I ran into 2 issues.

1. CPU utilization is still only ~35%
2. When testing larger working sets, the program stalls for several minutes before it starts iterating through each prime - I am assuming this has something to do with concurrent.futures's setup.

I was hoping someone could provide some insight into how to maximize system resource usage with this program and iron out the issues with larger sets.

Code below:

```
sys = platform.uname()
c = wmi.WMI()
winSys = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]

mode1 = "Integer Mode"
mode2 = "Floating-Point Mode"

def lehmer(p: int) -> bool:

    s = 4
    M = (1 << p) - 1
    for i in range(p - 2):
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
    return s == 0





#Initial printout of system information and menu screen schowing benchamrking options
print("_________________________________________________________________________________")
print("------------------------------System Information---------------------------------")
print(f"\tOS: {sys.system} {sys.release} ") #
print(f"\tMachine Name: {sys.node}")
print(f"\tVersion: {sys.version}")
print(f"\tCPU: {sys.processor}")
print("\tNumber of Cores: " + str(psutil.cpu_count()))
print(f"\tRAM: {psutil.virtual_memory()}")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------")


modeSelect = 0;
print("Welcome to ParaBench! Please select what benchmarking mode you would like to use." + '\n')
modeSelect = int(input("[1] -> " + mode1 + '\n' + "[2] -> " + mode2
    + "\n[9] -> Exit\n_________________________________________________________________________________\n"))


#User selects Integer benchmarking mode
if modeSelect == 1:
    print("User Selected " + mode1)

    #Printout of selection for order of magnitude
    print("[1] -> First 1x10^2 Primes\n" +  "[2] -> First 1x10^3 Primes\n"
        +"[3] -> First 1x10^4 Primes\n" + "[4] -> First 1x10^5 Primes\n" + "[5] -> First 1x10^6 Primes\n")
    mersenneOrder = int(input("Please Select an option\n"))


    if mersenneOrder == 1:
        print("Starting Benchmark...")
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(15) as executor:
            timeStart = perf_counter()

            for result in executor.map(lehmer,range(2,100)):
                print(result)
            timeStop = perf_counter()

            print("1E2 Benchmark Complete in ",timeStop-timeStart)


    if mersenneOrder == 2:
        print("Starting Benchmark...")
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(15) as executor:
            timeStart = perf_counter()

            for result in executor.map(lehmer,range(2,1000)):
                print(result)
            timeStop = perf_counter()
            print("1E3 Benchmark Complete!!", timeStop-timeStart)


    if mersenneOrder == 3:
        print("Starting Benchmark...")
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            timeStart = perf_counter()

            for result in executor.map(lehmer,range(2,10000)):
                print(result)
            timeStop = perf_counter()
            print("1E4 Benchmark Complete!!", timeStop-timeStart)


    if mersenneOrder == 4:
        print("Starting Benchmark...")
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(15) as executor:
            timeStart = perf_counter()

            for result in executor.map(lehmer,range(2,100000)):
                print(result)
            timeStop = perf_counter()
            print("1E5 Benchmark Complete!!", timeStop-timeStart)


    if mersenneOrder == 5:
        print("Starting Benchmark...")
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(15) as executor:
            timeStart = perf_counter()

            for result in executor.map(lehmer,range(2,1000000)):
                print(result)
            timeStop = perf_counter()
            print("1E6 Benchmark Complete!!", timeStop-timeStart)

        #Single-threaded test (DEPRECATED)
        #for x in range(2,1000000):
        #    if lehmer(x):
        #        print(x)
```

Comment: Python is a poor choice for this, you basically have to fight against the language (or the implementation) to stress all CPU cores.  Normally the CPython interpreter takes the Global Interpreter Lock when running a statement, so threads are mostly useful for I/O parallelism.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html mentions that `ProcessPoolExecutor` can avoid that, but I don't know much Python.

Comment: Try ProcessPoolExecutor. As mentioned, python only lets a single thread execute byte code. Threads wait on a global interpreter lock and take turns running.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just made the change to ProcessPoolExecutor and my utilization is up to 100!